# is it possible to use our custom keyboard instead of system keyboard in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard

in the flutter i create my custom keyboard i want when user tab on the Pin Put or Text Fields the system keyboard disable and user use the custom keyboard but I can not disable the android keyboard and set text in the Pin Put with custom number keyboard
is the any way to do this in the flutter?

Answer (score 0):

when tap TextFields tryo to call this function

```
void showCustomKeyboard(BuildContext context){
  SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide'); //hide keyboard
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode()); //unfocus current FocusNode
  showYourKeyBoard(); // this is your function to show your custom keyboard
}
```